# Powershell switch staging to production

Tags: powershell, azure

I have cloud service in azure.  And I have powershell script on continuous integration. I need on this powershell script switch staging to production. What cmdlet can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [`Move-AzureDeployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn495282.aspx) for that purpose. It will block until the swap is complete.